# SPLUNK : Duplicated json fields on searchHead

Tags: json, logging, configuration, splunk

I have clustered infrastructure (simplified)

2 SH (cluster) + 2 Indexer (cluster) + Heavy Forwarder (name HF)

On HF I run some script which returns me JSON file, and I forward it from HF to Indexers  (HF -> IndexCluser)

After that, I have to make some searches on SH with that data

When I make a search request, I have correctly parsed JSON, look perfect. BUT when I use `table` or just expand results each JSON field is duplicated.

I have a custom sourcetype defined on the Heavy Forwarder (although I tried some variations):

```
[just_json]

INDEXED_EXTRACTIONS = json
KV_MODE = none
AUTO_KV_JSON = false
NO_BINARY_CHECK = true
pulldown_type = true
category = Application
```

I assume that it multiplies on two because of:

JSON parsed during indexing (or sending from Heavy?)

JSON parsed additionally on searchHead during the search performed

I have read some similar questions (not sure about cluster case) but haven't succeeded.

Still can't figure out.

Some sample of event:

[view after query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAO0M.png)

[show raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjJlu.png)

[expanded view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYXGd.png)

Table view:
[table query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVrUK.png)

Comment: Please share the query you are using to display the JSON data.

Comment: @RichG hi! the simplest query - `index=someindex sourcetype="fwdjson:some_actions"` in that case i can see parsed events ,which looks fine, but when i expand (> button) - each field is doubled.
the second query `index=someindex sourcetype="fwdjson:some_actions" | table subject, action` shows me table view, and values are doubled in every cell.

Comment: I've seen this happen when both `INDEXED_EXTRACTIONS=json` and `KV_MODE=json` are specified, but that's not the case here.  I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: yeah, me too :(

Answer (score 0):

In all probability what you're describing is a *multivalue field* inside the JSON blob, and not a "duplicated" field. Please share some sample data to verify.

Are you seeing something like this in a `| table`?

```
FieldA | FieldB
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
BarA   | FooB
       | FooM
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
BarB   | FooA
       | FooG
```

If so, then in your JSON blob there are multiple values being tucked inside one of the key-value "pairs"

And you'll want to `mvexpand` them to get a one-for-one mapping in your table thusly:

```
<SPL before |table>
| mvexpand FieldB
| table FieldA FieldB
<any other SPL you have>
```

This will yield you a table like this:

```
FieldA | FieldB
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
BarA   | FooB
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
BarA   | FooM
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
BarB   | FooA
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
BarB   | FooG
```

Comment: @SPavel - that single event doesn't show the behavior you're asking about :)

Comment: it does. Each field in event dublicated. See `expanded view` link. The origin json doesn't contain dublicates. At `table view` you can see that it is not about single event, if it means some important for you.